# Spring Integration Test Binder doesn't mock dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have a project (https://github.com/serjteplov/demo-kafka-mock.git) where there are couple of dummy functions to read messages from kafka. In one of these functions  crudRepository is used to perform some operations against DB:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleFunctionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase(UserRepository userRepository) {

        String id = userRepository.findById("abc").map(User::getId).orElse(null);

        return value -> value.toUpperCase() + " id=" + id;
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> reverse() {
        return value -> new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

So the problem is to write test on uppercase binder function. To make this test works correctly I have to mock such call

```
userRepository.findById("abc")
```

then I've created mock and added it to the context:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean("test")
    UserRepository userRepository() {
        return new DetachedMockFactory().Mock(UserRepository)
    }
```

and mock call in the test:

```
userRepository.findById("abc") >> Optional.of(new User("abc", "Bob"))
```

[image]
After test execution mock is successfully created, but userRepository.findById("abc") still returns null.
Can anyone tell how to fix this problem? Or any alternative implementations and workarounds would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the stubbed method in the bean definition instead of in the function.

```java
@Bean
public Function<String, String> uppercase(UserRepository userRepository) {

    String id = userRepository.findById("abc").map(User::getId).orElse(null);

    return value -> value.toUpperCase() + " id=" + id;
}
```

Vs.

```java
@Bean
public Function<String, String> uppercase(UserRepository userRepository) {

    return value -> {
        String id = userRepository.findById("abc").map(User::getId).orElse(null);
        return value.toUpperCase() + " id=" + id;
    };

}
```